# Checking whether the input is empty or not without if statements

Tags: python

I need to check whether the input is empty or not and cannot use if statements.

```py
print("What is your name?")
name = input()
print("Hi, {}".format(name))
```

Comment: You could use `try` and `except` statements, or use `while` to see if length of input is not zero.

Comment: Who is saying you cannot use if statements?

Comment: What do you need to do if the input is empty?

Comment: I need to implement a program that ask for user's name, after getting user's name , print "Hi, user's name", if user did not put in a name or put in a empty name, then should print "You didn't key in any name"

Comment: Do you need to stop the code if the person does not key in any name?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop that only terminates if the length of `name` is 0:

```py
name = ""
while len(name) == 0:
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input()
print("Hi, {}".format(name))
```

Comment: `while not name:` works too

Comment: Agree, but I think this syntax is more intuitive for people that don't know about truthiness/falsiness.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `assert`. It will stop your programming to continue running when the requirement is not met.

```
print("What is your name?")
name = input()

assert name != "", "You didn't key in any name"
print("Hi, {}".format(name))


What is your name?

AssertionError: You didn't key in any name
```

Comment: You need to put the `assert` statement before the `print("Hi` part, otherwise `Hi` will always be printed (this does not match you output example.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
print("What is your name?")
name = input()

name = "Hi, {}".format(name)
while name == "Hi, ":
    name = "You didn't key in any name"

print(name)
```

This is ugly, but it will produce the exact output you want.

The idea is to use a loop that will run only once, and will only run if the `name` variable is empty after `input()` is called.

Comment: This is basically a glorified `if` statement.

Comment: @EpicProgrammer yes, but usually when someone gives a task of "don't use common operator X" the idea is to see how the programmer coerces another operator to do the same thing. If the OP was using Python 3.10 this could probably be done with pattern matching instead...

Comment: This is why I think these kinds of assignments are useless, because operators exist to do an option. And if/while statements are in different categories anyways, since one is for looping and one is for boolean conditions. Programming doesn't work well without the if statement, since that's how computers make decisions.

Comment: @EpicProgrammer as someone who actually had to interview potential developers, these kinds of questions are important, because they demonstrate the ability of a programmer to solve problems, not just use tools in a standard manner. It also shows understanding of the language, though usually these kinds  of questions are better formed than the one OP posted. Also, at the assembly level there is no `if`, that is a high level *imperative* language construct and programming can work fine without it. functional languages often try to avoid using it.

Comment: assembly still has the `cmp` instruction. Maybe it's not the same as a full if statement but it allows the program to do some conditional logic. Using a singular-turn while loop for conditional logic is very stupid.

Comment: @EpicProgrammer actually, `cmp` just performs a subtraction and discards the result, only setting flags. It does not change the flow of the code by it self. The real "workhorse" are the conditional jump commands, that check the flags and change the program counter accordingly. More often than not they are no paired with `cmp`, but that is besides the point.

Yes - it is a critical part of a Turing complete architecture to be able to change the execution path of the program. Yes, the code above is "stupid" because it avoids the most suitable tool for the job.

Comment: @EpicProgrammer but, it is important to understand that it is stupid only because a trivial example is used to practice. There are many different ways to change the flow of code, and under some circumstances we need to use a method that is not obvious. By forcing a programmer to abandon the most obvious solution for a trivial program, it is possible practice for these situation when they arise in non trivial code. Also, if you actually like programming, this can be a fun challenge. I do appreciate your criticism because it made me put in an effort to think of another solution!

Answer (score 0):

As my previous answer with the `while` loop received some criticism, I decided to demonstrate a less "naive" but perhaps more complicated solution, that actually does not use any kind of direct conditional operator:

```
print("What is your name?")
name = input()

answer = {}
answer[len(name)] = "Hi, {}".format(name)
answer[0] = "You didn't key in any name"


print(answer[len(name)])
```

Here we rely on a dictionary with the length of the input as an integer key.

We don't even need to compare the length to 0, we just overwrite the 0 key with the error message.

If input length is greater than 0, the name will be under its own key, and will be printed, if not, the empty "Hi" string will be replaced.

Would this ever be useful in the real world?
Probably not, unless there are many more than 2 options.

Does it comply with the task requirements?
Yes. It gives the desired output.